# Create (or duplicate) div with Dojo content dynamically

Tags: dojo, struts2, dynamic

I have to develop a project using Struts2 & Dojo.
I would like to create a div containing Dojo widgets by clicking on a button.
For example :

```
 <s:form data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Form" 
        data-dojo-props="method: 'post',
        action: 'myAction'"
        theme="simple">
    <s:div id="myId">
        <s:textfield
            name="aName"
            data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TimeTextBox"
            data-dojo-props="name: 'aName'" />
        // More Dojo widgets ...
    </s:div>
</s:form>
```

I would like a Javascript function that "duplicate" the "myDiv" Div and place it below te previous one, and so on ...

The final result could be something like that :

```
 <s:form data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Form" 
        data-dojo-props="method: 'post',
        action: 'myAction'"
        theme="simple">
    <s:div id="myId">
        <s:textfield
            name="aName"
            data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TimeTextBox"
            data-dojo-props="name: 'aName'" />
        // More Dojo widgets ...
    </s:div>
    <s:div id="myId_2">
        <s:textfield
            name="aName"
            data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TimeTextBox"
            data-dojo-props="name: 'aName'" />
        // More Dojo widgets ...
    </s:div>
    <s:div id="myId_3">
        <s:textfield
            name="aName"
            data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TimeTextBox"
            data-dojo-props="name: 'aName'" />
        // More Dojo widgets ...
    </s:div>
</s:form>
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Cloning DOM nodes with dijits inside can be a little tricky. The `dojo.clone` function will clone the dijits' DOM nodes, but it will not do the calls to `dojo.connect`, register it with the dijit registry and so on. You'll get boxes that look like dijits, but don't work. Consider it sort of like photocopying a booklet, but not stapling the pages together.

Your best bet is to make a clone of myDiv before Dojo's parser parses it. That means you can't have parseOnLoad set to true in your Dojo config.

For example, make the clone and store it somewhere in `dojo.ready` and run the parser manually at the end:

```
var clonableDiv, 
    numClones = 0;

dojo.ready(function()
{
    clonableDiv = dojo.clone( dojo.byId("myId") );
    dojo.parser.parse();
});
```

Now, let's say you have a button with id "myButton", used to add clones to the form:

```
dojo.connect("myButton", "onclick", function()
{
    var newClone = dojo.clone(clonableDiv);
    newClone.setAttribute("id", "myId_" + numClones);
    newClone.childNodes[1].setAttribute("data-dojo-props", "name: 'aName_" + numClones + "'");
    dojo.place(newClone, dojo.byId("myId"), "after");
    numClones++;
    dojo.parser.parse(newClone);
});
```

There are a few things to notice here. Firstly, you have to make sure you don't insert a duplicate id in the document. The same goes for the input fields' name attributes. Also, after you have inserted the clone, you need to explicitly parse the new inserted div.

It does get a bit messy, especially if you have multiple nodes or widgets with ids or names that you have to make sure are unique. At some point it may even be just as tidy to build everything programmatically instead of cloning myId. Alternatively, you can create a custom widget for the repeatable area.